# Understanding multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, ant, ant-contrib

I have questions regarding the multithread processign using Ant fork approach

**Below are the Jar files and associated java classes and methods**

Test1.jar has
--Test1.java has
--MethodA()

Test2.jar has
  --Test2.java has
  --MethodB()

Test3.jar has
  --Test3.java has
  --MethodC()

**runtime.classpath will have**: Test1.jar,Test2.jar and Test3.jar

**testsuite.list:** Test1.tsv,Test2.tsv,Test3.tsv

```
Test1.tsv --> calls MethodC(), MethodB(), MethodA() in sequence
Test2.tsv --> calls MethodA(), MethodB(), MethodA() in sequence
Test3.tsv --> calls MethodB(), MethodA(), MethodA() in sequence
```

Ant sciprt:

```
<for list="${testsuite.list}" param="testsuite" parallel="true" threadCount="3">
 <sequential>
    <local name="cmdLine.args" />
    <property name="cmdLine.args" value="--variable ENV:${env.file} --listener TListener ${tag.option} @{testsuite}"/>
    <java classname="org.TestWork"  classpathref="runtime.classpath" fork="true" maxmemory="1024M">
        <arg line="${cmdLine.args}"/>
    </java>
 </sequential>
</for>
<java classname="org.TestWork"  classpathref="runtime.classpath" fork="true" maxmemory="1024M">
  <arg value="--output"/>
  <arg value="output.xml"/>
</java>
```

When Ant scripts triggered

Thread 1 pickup Test1.tsv
Thread 2 pickup Test2.tsv
Thread 3 pickup Test3.tsv

Now my question is when 3 threads executing in parallel, 3 instances of each Test1.java, Test2.java and Test3.java are created Or there will be only one instance of Test1.java, Test2.java and Test3.java?

If only one instance of Test1.java, Test2.java and Test3.java created while Thread1 exeucting MethodA() , Thread2 has to wait until Thread1 completes MethodA() execution?

Can some help me to understand this. Also, is there a way I can know how many threads executing given method at a time , is there any locking happening or how many java instances created?

Other point to note is my MethodA(),MethodB(),MethodC() has implementations that have wait time and retry mechanism to look for web elements. So I am not sure when multiple threads executing what’s happening .. Sometime I am seeing lot of delay to complete method execution so wondering if there is any locking happening.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description, I there are some shared global resources that are accessed by threads. So threads should be sharing common resources not separated ones.

> If only one instance of Test1.java, Test2.java and Test3.java created
>   while Thread1 exeucting MethodA() , Thread2 has to wait until Thread1
>   completes MethodA() execution?

Yes, Correct. But no one can guarantees the order.

> Also, is there a way I can know how many threads executing given
>   method at a time?

Yes, There are few ways to do,

- You can use a lock + another protected global variable that will be incremented at the start of the method & decremented at the end of the method. (Old way - more explicit)
- A semaphore - you can use [getQueueLength()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#getQueueLength()) for this purpose. (***Easiest way*** - less explicit implementation)
- A [synchronized block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440281/5715934).

I prefer the second one (a semaphore) since it is the most powerful & easiest.

> is there any locking happening or how many java instances created?

There will not be any default locking happening unless you implemented or used `synchronized`.

Comment: 1. Yes jar is library. How can i confirm for each Test*.tsv file separate java instance created instead sharing the same instance among the all threads
2. Also, let say 100 threads trying to execute MethodA() at a time what happens in this case 99 threads will wait until first thread completed or while thread1 working thread2 will also make the changes and give the abrupt results 

appreciate your inputs

Comment: (1) If you are using the library without creating global objects, it is separate. I think you got my point. For a more clear answer can you please put your code?? Otherwise there can be misunderstandings. :)) (2) Abrupt results would not be happened, if you have implemented a proper locking mechanism. .. Again please put your code here, so that I can answer accordingly, otherwise what all I can do is giving generic comments. :))

Comment: For1:
I have multiple java files so can't able to post all the code. 
all i can say is In java class i have static variables and methods those are being accessed in other classes. And some classes has thread wait time So, in this case even if Thread 1 pickup Test1.tsv Thread 2 pickup Test2.tsv Thread 3 pickup Test3.tsv with given ant xml configuration. still separagted instances crated static methods class instances shared among all threads?.  what do you mean by global objects.

Comment: For 2:
My general question is 
let say 100 threads trying to execute MethodA() in call Test1.java at a time what happens in this case? 99 threads will wait until first thread completed or while thread1 working thread2 will also try to make the changes ? to avoid this i have to implement synchronize?

Comment: @gorants (1) Based on your comment I think it is the other way around. So it is the same instance. You say that you are using static variables for shared resources, so it is what I am referring as global. Please refer the updated answer. (2) you can't count #threads when you are using synchronized for whole method. You can do it with a lock or it will be rather easy to use a semaphore. Please refer the updated answer. :))